# Can a xib be edited in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to edit a xib within a Xamarin.iOS project in Visual Studio? I found this

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/31353/is-it-possible-to-re-design-a-xib-in-visual-studio

but it is over a year old. Then there is this from a slightly later date contradicting the statement that you cannot open a xib in visual studio from Alan McGovern a Xamarin employee.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55937/xamarin-5-10-xib-support#latest

When opening the xib within visual studio it appears to be trying to render the UI preview rather than giving some error about not being able to open in Visual Studio.

[image]

**Specs**

Running in Visual Studio Professional 2015 connected to MAC with full support.

- Xamarin.iOS 9.6.2.4
- XCode 7.3.1
- Mono 4.2.3

**Xib**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="7706" systemVersion="14F27" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
  <dependencies>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="7703" />
  </dependencies>
  <objects>
    <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="RISCAuction_AssignmentInfo">
      <connections>
        <outlet property="view" destination="2" id="RRd-Eg-VrN" />
      </connections>
    </placeholder>
    <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder" />
    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="2">
      <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600" />
      <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite" />
    </view>
  </objects>
</document>
```

Comment: xib files do open in Visual studio 2015. But if you are using an xib file created in xcode then you will have to use the `sync with xcode` option in xamarin studio as it will create your designer file in c# and then I try to open it in Visual studio.

Comment: The file was created in visual studio it currently contains no elements but fails to ever open to the blank designer page within visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is yes. After trying to open the same xib for hours yesterday and watching it sit on the progress bar never opening today it does open. Not sure why it take so long but you can indeed edit xibs from VS.

Comment: Every time you tried did you have a connection to the build Mac?

Comment: Yes. I think I just needed to reboot the Mac book pro. It still takes quite a while to open but it does open after reboot.

Comment: There's a number of daemons that start on the Mac for Xamarin - you can watch them in the lower left corner of Visual Studio. Funnily enough, you can now compile/build in Visual Studio without a Mac connection and it's nice and fast, but add the Mac (to run the sim or deploy on an iDevice) and it takes forever. It can take a minute before the launch XIB pops up on my machine. :(

Comment: Might as well put all this in an answer, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an established connection from Visual Studio to you Mac. That alone can take a while to happen. Watch in the lower left corner for messages, as well as for icon in the menu bar to turn green.

Even then, when opening the XIB it can take quite a while - a minute or so more in my case. And I use a decent PC with a Hackintosh VM on the same machine, so it certainly isn't network latency.